# Looking into details on difference between using somthing like t1.col1 = t2.col1 vs using join in an SQL query

Tags: sql, mysql

I am fairly new to SQL, so I need guidance on better ways to write queries related to joins, especially on its optimization concepts.

Approach 1 - Without join

```
Select sum(ci.population) from city ci, country co
where co.continent = 'Asia'
and co.code = ci.countrycode;
```

Approach 2 - With Join

```
SELECT sum(ci.population)
FROM city ci 
Left JOIN country co
ON ci.countrycode = co.code
WHERE co.continent = 'Asia'
```

Both approaches give us the same result. In that case, is one of the methods better than the other? If so, why?

I have tried both below approaches and they give the same result but since I am working on a small db, I am curious whether one of the approaches will be better as far as optimization goes when working with larger dbs.

Approach 1 - Without join

```
Select sum(ci.population) from city ci, country co
where co.continent = 'Asia'
and co.code = ci.countrycode;
```

Approach 2 - With Join

```
SELECT sum(ci.population)
FROM city ci 
Left JOIN country co
ON ci.countrycode = co.code
WHERE co.continent = 'Asia'
```

Comment: [Bad habbits](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins); even the article is ~15 years old.

Comment: The co.continent condition in the WHERE clause makes your LEFT JOIN return regular INNER JOIN result. Move the condition to the ON clause to get true LEFT JOIN result. (However, you want a regular INNER JOIN here.)

Comment: Hi Jarlh, thanks for commenting, just to mention the example I have used above is just there to reference my approaches not the exact dataset I am confused or stuck on. But what I got from your comment in that when we use the co.code = ci.countrycode in where clause it will always be an inner join. So in cases where I want a left join/ right join or full join just using the above condition in where clause will not give the right results. Please let me know if there is something wrong in my understanding.

Comment: Hi Stu, thank for commenting, The blog is very helpful and relevant to what I was looking for.

Comment: Correct, "outer table" conditions need to be in the ON clause for outer joins.

Comment: BTW, query 1 is doing a join too, an implicit join. (Not recommended.)

Comment: Ok, got it thanks again! Marking this question as closed.

Answer (score 0):

This doubt has been clarified based on the comments from the above users. Adding this answer to mark the question complete.